# Is Vert.x JDBCClient thread-safe?

Tags: jdbc, vert.x, vertx-verticle

Is Vert.x `JDBCClient` (`JDBCClientImpl`) thread-safe, meaning could multiple threads use same instance of `JDBCClient` without any impact?

I'm creating `JDBClient` instance using shared datasource by doing `JDBCClient.createShared(vertx, config)` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the client is thread safe